# Error: expected initializer before ': ' token , gcc compiler

Tags: c++, gcc

I encounter this error when I am trying to compile a c++ code via a Makefile.

```
error: expected initializer before ':' token
```

I have checked the compatibility of the compiler of my system
I also checked the paths etc. I also did some test; such as adding a semicolon after the 2nd declaration of class but didnt work. I have little to no experience with c++, the script is not even written by me; it is part of vtk library (Visualisation toolkit). Part of the script  from where
the error generates is:

```
#ifndef __vtkProcessObject_h
#define __vtkProcessObject_h

#include "vtkAlgorithm.h"

class vtkDataObject;

class VTK_FILTERING_EXPORT vtkProcessObject : public vtkAlgorithm
{
public:
   vtkTypeRevisionMacro(vtkProcessObject,vtkAlgorithm);
   void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent);
```

I get the error in `line 8`.

Probably it is something really straightforward, but as I said I have no clue how this language works.

Comment: what are the contents of `vtkAlgorithm.h`?  It'd be interesting to see the definition for `VTK_FILTERING_EXPORT` and declaration for `class vtkAlgorithm`

Comment: Looks like VTK_FILTERING_EXPORT is not #define'd and the compiler treats it as the variable name. Try preprocessing the source file.

Comment: I recommend that you use CMake to generate your vtk makefile. This will handle the defines, includes linking...

Comment: @harper You are probably right. The VTK_FILTERING_EXPORT is defined by another vtk*.h script which is not in the library. @simonc vtkAlgorithm is actually a superclass including all sources & filters.  I don't see a declaration `class vtkAlgorithm` in the default script. @drescherjm  I will look into it, because this means that Cmakelists should be in the source directory if I am right, and  there aren't at the moment. Thanks to all.

Comment: Yes you should have a CMakeLists.txt in the root folder of your project source code if CMake is being used to generate the project file or makefile.

Answer (score 0):

The VTK_FILTERING_EXPORT macro is defined in a header, and is largely there for Windows and/or GCC symbol visibility. You don't mention what version of VTK you are compiling, but using CMake to generate the Makefiles would ensure the correct include paths are set up. If this is Linux, and the GCC visibility functionality has not been activated you could define the macro to nothing, but I suspect you would hit many other issues once you got past this point in the compilation.